# Overriding canBecomeKeyWindow in objective C + cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am making a GUI in xcode using the interface builder with objective C and Cocoa. I am trying to create an NSTextField which I can edit. According to many sources, the problem is that the `NSWindow` class has defaults for `canBecomeKeyWindow` and `canBecomeMainWindow` which prohibit this from happening. The solution is apparently to implement a subclass of `NSWindow` which overrides these variables. Here is my attempt:

```
// new window class to allow text fields to be used
@interface NewWindow : NSWindow
@end

@implementation NewWindow
- (BOOL) canBecomeKeyWindow {return NO;}
- (BOOL) canBecomeMainWindow {return NO;}
@end


// here the window property is added
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (strong) IBOutlet NewWindow *window;
@end
```

Unfortunately, this is still not working. I realize that this question has been asked about 1000 times on stack overflow but I have been struggling for hours since I have not seen an explicit solution anywhere. Can someone let me know what the problem is?

Edit: not sure if this is important but I have changed the class of the window in the interface builder to the new one: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcbN3.jpg)

Edit 2: I put this in my code, found on another stack overflow post:

```
if([_window isKeyWindow] == TRUE) {
    NSLog(@"isKeyWindow!");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"It's not KeyWindow!");
}
```

My subclass is indeed changing the keywindow state of the Window. However, I still cannot edit the textfield. Any thoughts?

Comment: The problem is you just declaring the property as `NewWindow` but you are still probably creating a `NSWindow`. You have to create an instance of `NewWindow`. This would be more obvious in Swift.

Comment: What would a potential solution to this problem look like?

Comment: Why do you want to edit a textfield in a inactive window?